# I would like to autoatically generate tags/keys that summarize each text document I have so i can search for them by tags/keys

Tags: python, search

## In Short

**I would like a software recommendation that summarizes a long text document and produces keywords for that text document. Ideally, it will exclude words like "with, and, the, etc." and include more important words. Ideally so i can script using Python3**

I am unfamiliar with search engines but I know they have indexing techniques to rank keywords that summarize documents/webpages. My particular scenario does not require such a sophisticated suite (SQL databases and indexing entire filesystems, etc.). All my documents that I am interest to find are in one directory, so linux terminal utilities like `grep` are sufficient to parse. Maybe a full suite will perform better?

I have looked at [PyLucene](http://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/) but it seems to have a lot more than I need. **Can someone please give some recommendations for software or what kind of field of study this is, so I can do some of my own research, is it called indexing?**

> ### Explanation of issue
>
> I have hundreds of text documents (with a unique made-up file extension, `.crp`). Each of these `.crp` files describe, in plain text, a scenario for an experiment (basically a `README`) for the logs that my program generated.
>
> For example I have directory called `scanario_1` which contains a `description.crp`  and `.log` files for the experiment. The `description.crp` describes the conditions under which the `.log` files were generated.
>
> I write a each detailed `description.crp` file manually and also manually generate a `keywords.crp` file which summarizes the `description.crp` file. So I can perform queries on the `keywords.crp` files and not have to search the lengthy description.
>
> Problem is, as I analyze the logs for performance and make notes on it (update the `description.crt`) I have to then go an update each `keyword.crp` file. **And I would like to automate the creation of the `keyword.crp` files by having something read the `description.crt` file and produce the keywords**